# prev and next returning undefined instead page numbers in pagination

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom, pagination

I am trying to create pagination with the below code and I am facing the problem to access page number `($clickedPageLink.dataset.page)` when I click `Prev` and `Next` links. However,  I am able to successfully get the page number when I click page number `1 to 5`. Please find the plunker for reference [Pagination](https://plnkr.co/edit/VWPdx0SkwWsdDrTi?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview).  When click `Prev` and `Next`,  `console.log($clickedPageLink.dataset.page)` is giving `undefined`. Can any one help to get the values for `Prev` and `Next` also as given in html?

```
let prevVal = 2;
let nextVal = 3;

let str = ['<nav class="pagination">'];
str.push('<ul class="pagination__pages">');
str.push('<li class="pagination__page pagination--previous">');
str.push('<a class="pagination__link" data-page="' + (prevVal - 1) + '" href="#">');
str.push('<span><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i> Prev</span>');
str.push('</a></li>');
for (let plengthMn = 1; plengthMn <= 5; plengthMn++) {
   str.push('<li class="pagination__page">');
   str.push('<a class="pagination__link" data-page="' + plengthMn + '" href="#">' + plengthMn + '</a>');
   str.push('</li>');
}

str.push('<li class="pagination__page pagination--next">');
str.push('<a class="pagination__link" data-page="' + (nextVal + 1) + '" href="#">');
str.push('<span>Next <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span>');
str.push('</a></li>');
const $paginationList = document.getElementById('products-item_pagination');
$paginationList.innerHTML  = str.join('');

const $paginationLinkMn = document.querySelectorAll('.pagination__link');

function attachEventToElementList(elmList, event, eventHandler) {
    if(!elmList) {
        return;
    }

    elmList.forEach(function(elm) {
        elm.addEventListener(event, eventHandler);
    });
}

attachEventToElementList($paginationLinkMn, 'click', goToPageMn); 

 
   function goToPageMn(event) {
    const $clickedPageLink = event.target;
    console.log($clickedPageLink.dataset.page)

}
```

And in my html, I have,

```
 <div id="products-item_pagination" class="product-pagination"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above code is, the event is never firing up for `anchor tag` which is the parent of `prev icon`. Below css hack has solved the problem.

```
a > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```